# ASPX Page to listen to SOAP Request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Need to write a code in aspx on server B to get data fom soap request sent by a server A to server B. Server A has an application which can send an XML at any web address where I need to put a code to get data from that XML.

Comment: Are you saying you need to consume a SOAP web service from a c# application?

Comment: I need to integrate 2 tools, tool a and tool b. So tool b will post some xml on an aspx page that i need to create. Then i need to get that XML as it is POSTed ony webpage.